# An error when trying to aggregate using data.table

Tags: r, data.table

table users,

I have the code as shown in the screenshot and the resulting error. Unfortunately I can't share the data due to privacy issues. Does anyone have an idea of the error?

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `by`, the resulting `data.table` should have one row per group. However, you try to assign multiple values to each of these lines by using `unique()` (given there are multiple unique values per group). You either have to wrap them in `list()` or `paste(..., collapse = ", ")` or something like that to just get a single value in each by.